# I am a giant in my scene very large

Tags: camera, navigation

I have a very huge scene, and i walk (navigation) , it take few step
to cross the terrain, and on another project my scene is tiny,
but the walk navigation is ok , it's take a lot of step to
cross. In the huge scene i cross it like i'm a giant.
How to change this behavior.

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/walk_fly.html), you can change the walk/ fly speed using either the numeric keypad or your mouse scroll wheel:

[image]

If you want to change your view height, you can do so under *File -> Preferences -> Navigation -> Gravity -> View Height*.

Comment: You don't understand, my camera is 20m above the ground, like a giant, i'm unable to walk in my forest, i made, whereas in other scene, i'm able to walk very close to the ground

Comment: What do you mean "walk in" the scene? If you want the camera to be close to the ground you can place it next to the ground. What's the issue? Please be more specific.

Comment: Oh Alexandre, it was my mistake, i was sure that my landscape was huge, but finally the landscape was just 23m x 23m and my 200 trees was little, i change it for 144m x 144m and i growth my trees more, and now i can walk like i am in forest.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati camera view has a walk/fly mode